# Appengine images on Reportlab pdf

Tags: python-2.7, app-engine-ndb, reportlab

Python 2.7, Google App Engine, ndb.Model

I have .jpg images stored as

```
signblobkey      = ndb.BlobKeyProperty(verbose_name='Signature')
```

These store and display in html pages perfectly.  However, I can't figure out how to 'print' these in a .pdf with reportlab.

My current code is:

```
blobattach = ''
blobname   = ''
blobmime   = 'None'
if self.filetext.signblobkey != None:
    blob_info  = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(self.filetext.signblobkey)
blobmime   = blob_info.content_type[:5]
blobname   = blob_info.filename
if blobmime == 'image':
    blobattach = get_serving_url(self.filetext.signblobkey)          

canvas.ImageReader(StringIO.StringIO(self.filetext.signblobkey))
self.p.drawImage(image=blobattach,
                 x=self.colleft, 
                 y=c_lineprint - (4 * self.lineheight), 
                 width=self.colright - self.colleft, 
                 height=4 * self.lineheight, 
                 mask=None, 
                 preserveAspectRatio=True, 
                 anchor='nw')
```

I am obviously missing something here, I don't seem to be accessing the actual image.  Any clues for me?

Thanks, 
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, what you're passing as the `image` to `self.p.drawImage` is just `blobattach`, which, at best, is just a URL. You probably need to pass it an image.

You could try to pass that URL to `ImageReader` (which apparently knows how to make use of a URL) and use the result as the image. What you're passing right now to `ImageReader` is a not a URL. I'm not quite sure what it is - I doubt `StringIO` (or `ImageReader` for that matter) knows what to do with a blob key (your `self.filetext.signblobkey`).

Or you could try to read the image from the blobstore directly, from your `self.filetext.signblobkey`. Something along these lines (you need to use the blobstore API to properly interpret a blob key):

```
with blobstore.BlobReader(self.filetext.signblobkey) as fd:
     blob_content = fd.read()
```

Not sure how exactly how it'd work, tho, I didn't play with images (yet).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the above answer which lead me in the right direction.  Just in case anyone else needs help, I finally...

```
from reportlab.lib.utils import ImageReader

# note self.filetext is a ndb.Model with .signblobkey pointing to my signature
self.signature = None
if self.filetext.signblobkey != None:
    blob_info  = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(self.filetext.signblobkey)
    blobmime   = blob_info.content_type[:5]
    blobname   = blob_info.filename
    if blobmime == 'image':
        blobattach     = get_serving_url(self.filetext.signblobkey)  
        self.signature = ImageReader(blobattach)

# in the printing routine (I will print a few thousand pages, each with a signature
if self.signature:
    self.p.drawImage(image=self.signature, 
                     x=self.colleft, 
                     y=c_lineprint - (4 * self.lineheight), 
                     width=self.colright - self.colleft, 
                     height=4 * self.lineheight, 
                     mask=None, 
                     preserveAspectRatio=True, 
                     anchor='nw')
```